# Изменение адреса роутера без изменения отображаемой страницы в NUXT

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Есть страница в накст с урл https://myurl.ru/main с карточками товаров.
как по клику на карточку товара  перейти на урл https://myurl.ru/main/item но при этом на заднем фоне отображается страница https://myurl.ru/main а поверх нее открыта модалка с подробным описанием товара по которому кликнули. примерно такого вида [image: открыта карточка товара]

Comment: У Вас модалка должна быть в глобальном компоненте, допустим, в `layouts/[компонент]` (например, `layouts/default`). Подтягиваете туда модалку, она инициализируется один раз. При открытии туда подтягиваете данные (через Vuex можно сделать).  Дальше можете по страницам куда угодно ходить - модалка всегда будет открыта, т.к зависит только от `layout`.

Comment: Решил вопрос просто добавив элементы которые должны быть на фоне в общий шаблон, а отличия догружаю уже при переключении по страницам